# Why is "qaautomation.net" missing from the html source code?

Tags: java, html, selenium

For the example program on the webpage

http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=263

I carry out the following steps:

1. Run the program with the driver.close() line of code commented out.
2. The program opens a Firefox browser, then searches for the term "qa automation".
3. Once the "Test passed." message has been printed to the screen (in the console), go to the google search results page.
4. Using the browser menu, go to Tools/Web Developer/Page Source.
5. On the page source page, search for the term "qaautomation.net".

I get no search results in Step 5. Why is the text "qaautomation.net" not present in the source code.

The webpage displayed by Firefox shows the text "qaautomation.net" as one of its search results. Also, the following line of code

```
return driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().contains("qaautomation.net");
```

in the program must return true since Step 3 above completes. Why does the method getText() above appear to find the text "qaautomation.net" when I can't find it in the source code? Any help on this would be appreciated.

EDIT

I have now asked a new question in relation to this query.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see qaautomation.net in the google results? As part of the link or the description under the link or ? When you search in the HTML source, you are passing if you find it *anywhere* which may not be what you want or the best idea. I would suggest that you look for it in a particular place, the link or below the link or both. Then target your search there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking into wrong place. Page source of that option show you css, JS everything.

You need to look into HTML DOM.

In your 4th step do as below:-

Right click on page -> Inspect Element

Or go to Tools/Web Developer/Inspector.

Now use cntr + F // to find the string qaautomation.net

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks Shubham Jain, that's helpful - now I know about inspector. One thing still baffles me: if I open a Firefox browser manually (i.e. not by running the program), go to google.com, search for "qa automation", then go to Tools/Web Developer/Page Source, "qaautomation.net" is there! Is that because that text is, in this instance, linked to JS functions?